# JMeter - How to execute a thread group every 10 minutes ( What is the best practice ? )

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a situation where an API is called by 500 users/threads every 10 minutes.

I have created a jmeter script for this. It takes around 4 to 5 minutes to get response for all the 500 threads.

Now I have created a batch file to execute this jmx file. This batch file is then called every 10 minutes using task scheduler in windows.

I am not sure whether this is the best approach.

Have read about test action sampler / Timers / Think time etc.

Please can someone advise which is recommended in my case.

My requirement is to trigger the thread group every 10 minutes irrespective of how long the the previous run took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds)

> If it compiles, it is good; if it boots up, it is perfect

Given your approach works fine for your use case you should be good to go.

Personally I would be interested in test results as well (not sure how you're handling them), perhaps a better idea would be putting your script under orchestration of a [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server like [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/), it provides flexible options on triggering the jobs (including scheduling) and you will be able to get some statistics, trends and conditionally mark your tests as passed or failed basing on the response time using [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin/)